Azure Functions unable to start locally: can't find Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=8.0.0.0
Recently I wanted to debug my Azure Function, but all of a sudden it started to throw error:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.

So, I suspected that I have some old package reference after upgrading to .NET8. But, strangely I have no references to this library. And my project is using .NET8.
Could not try much, as I am not even sure what is the reason for that.
The main question is rather what are possible reasons for that? I can take care of potential fix.

After digging around the issue for a while, i found this post on MS forum, but little different, as it was failing in Azure.
However, fix was actually the same - missing app settings for Azure Functions, I had to specify in my configuration:
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
        "FUNCTIONS_INPROC_NET8_ENABLED": "1",
        "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~4",
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
    }
}

Reference: App settings reference for Azure Functions
